# Sequence of irreducible polynomials

Tags: prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Does there exist a sequence of nonzero integers $a_n$ such that for all $n$ the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ is irreducible if:

1) every $a_n$ is prime;

2) all $a_n$ are pair wise coprime;

3) no other conditions?

I heard problem 2 was asked somewhere but I don't know neither answer nor the source.

Comment: for part 3, see [cyclotomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) polynomial

Comment: If you mean constant sequence $a_n = 1$, then polynomial will be irreducible if only $n+1$ is prime, as far as I know.

Comment: For part 3, take $a_0=1$ and $a_k=2$ for all $k\ge1$; then each polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion (applied to the reciprocal polynomial, if you like).